# How to find element with Enzyme unit testing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chai, enzyme

I have a unit test that uses that contains function which works. Is it possible to select an node from a collection and then take the text property? I tried this:

```
it('should be equaling name property', () => {
        const props = {
            myprops: [{
                email: "blaat@mail.com",
                name: "Coco Chanel"
            }]
        };
        const wrapper = shallow(<ServiceDetails {...props} />);
        expect(wrapper.find('div')[0].text).equals('Cici Chanel');
 });
```

This is part of my reactjs component:

```
  return (
          <section>
                <div>{email}</div>
                <div>{name}</div>
          </section>
  )
```

However I am getting this error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
```

How can I select the second div and take the value that is in that div?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would need to uniquely identify the div:

```
expect(wrapper.find('section div:nth-of-type(1)').text()).equals('Cici Chanel');
```

or better:

```
return (
      <section>
            <div className="div1">{email}</div>
            <div>{name}</div>
      </section>
)

expect(wrapper.find('.div1').text()).equals('Cici Chanel');
```

Also [`text` is function](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/text.md), not property.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following code works

```
const component = wrappper.find('section.div')
expect(component.at(0).text()).toEqual('Cici chanel')
```